# e.preventDefault() causes :active state to stick on anchor

Tags: javascript, jquery, preventdefault

So I'm using the HTML5 history API to transition fro view to view in my .js app.

I have an `$('a').click` function which executes `e.preventDefault()` followed by a route transition:

```
$("a").click(function (event) {
  if (this.host === window.location.host && this.getAttribute('data-bypass') === null) {
    event.preventDefault()
    indexRouter.navigate(this.pathname, true)
  }
})
```

This works just fine, except that in WebKit browsers, the anchor's state gets stuck on `:active`. How can I get it to return to the normal anchor state when the move is released?

Least-hacky answer will be accepted, there are a number of jacky ways to do this I am sure.

## Update #1:

The best solution I've found so far that works is to detach and reattach the element with [bonzo](https://github.com/ded/bonzo):

```
var previous = $(this).previous()
  , next = $(this).next()
  , parent = $(this).parent()
  , detached = $(this).detach()

if (previous.length) previous.after(detached)
else if (next.length) next.before(detached)
else if (parent.length) parent.append(detached)
else $('body').append(detached)
```

but it's a LOT of code for something so trivial.

## Update #2:

Update #1 is the only thing that seems to work, and a lot of code is fine, I made it into a reusable function called `$.reset()`. One issue remains:

When you click the link your cursor changes from the `pointer` cursor to the `default` cursor, which feels awkward.

Is there no way to get this to work? I've been doing web development for a long time and it seems like this is a recent bug in WebKit which has made it into Safari 7 and Chrome 23 or so.

Comment: DOn't use "click" - try to use mousedown and let the mouseup pass through. Should work in WebKit too.

Comment: @ErnestV but if mouse up passes through, the browser executes the navigation and the page is reloaded. This breaks my backbone routes!

Comment: Just a thought, never tried this, but `$(event.target).blur()` could do what you want.

Comment: @ErnestV that does not work, but a solution similar to that would. I don't think the blur event stops :active.

Comment: Last try before I give up for today ;-) `$('body').focus()`

Comment: @ErnestV nope. Nothing seems to work. `.addClass('inactive')` with a CSS style behind it solves the problem, but that's so hacky I could never live with myself.